# how to automate web testing using Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My requirement is very simple:

1. I have to login to my company's website
2. Go to a specific page that contains reports/Insights represented as charts(PBI reports)
3. select values from the dropdown in the filters available, click apply
4. Capture the values/units represented in the chart
5. Compare the captured values against the database
6. Return the results

I know how to connect to database, run queries and store the output but i am fairly new to the web test automation part. I also know that we could use RPA framework to automate Web testing but the team doesn't want to have a separate framework from the existing ones.

The chart are PBI visuals embedded in the web page. I cannot share a screenshot of the web page as we are not supposed to share them in a public forum.

can someone help me understand how i can achieve the above mentioned steps using the Python script? can it be done with request and beautifulsoup modules or is there a better to do it?
Any ideas are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

UI Web testing is done by running automated browsers though special drivers.

There are several wrapper-libs around that drivers, most popular ones is: `Selenium`, `Playwright` and `Puppeteer`

I recomend using `playwright` as it's the most modern and convinient one.

You could start from ["Getting Started"](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) section of docs

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to start with beautifulsoap and selenium. It's pretty easy. Just go into their docs and you'll understand after few minutes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).